# Aws Lambda Postman eror: "message": "Internal server error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, rest

I'm writing a Python Apigateway with Aws Lambda. I made the api settings, I set up a rest-api and tested it both on lambda and on postman.

```
import json



def response(res):
    return {
    'statusCode' : 200,
    'body' : json.dumps(res),
    'headers' : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #event['body'] içeriğe ulaşım
    body = event['body']

# TODO implement
    return response(body)
```

and this is my request

```
{
  "cityName": "Postman City "
}
```

aws result:it's ok
but postman side is burn

This is Postman eror output

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

this is my simplest code, I'm really freaked out by this mistake.
As I understand it, when I play with the event in lambda_handler(event, context): the API connection is broken and it gives an internal error.
When I run it with event['any'] the lambda test works but the postman side is faulty.

I am sure that my API settings are correct because when I return to a simple return status, the problem disappears

```
{
        'statusCode' : 200,
        'body' : "it's bullshet",
        'headers' : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }
```

ok I've been looking at this for 2 days. I tried to use the event data from the dict as a list, string or dict with different libraries, but my errors did not change.

So what can I do with aws if I'm not going to use requests to be sent to me with the event?
Waiting for your solutions...

Comment: Did you check cloudwatch logs for error messages from your function?

Comment: yes i looked there first but i can't say i understand the details...

Comment: Why not post the error message in the question?

Comment: How can I get this?
Do you want the response statement or the cloudwatch output?

Comment: Just edit the question with the error message.